# Best practices for writing xpath selectors

Tags: python, xml, xpath, scrapy

I started learning xpath and python scrapy. So far I have learned basics of these two.But now I need to know how the efficient xpath selectors can be defined and some best practices in both scrapy and xpath.Is there any good web resources that will help me?

Comment: For scrapy Scrapy docs are great http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/index.html and for lpath w3org http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/ have shared deep explanation.

Comment: The best practice is the same as with any other programming topic: Read tutorials, websites or books and take your time to learn and experiment. If you have *specific* questions, ask them here.

Answer (score 2):

Despite that the question is too broad, I would still leave a point here.

`Scrapy` has it's own mechanism for parsing the HTML and extracting the data, but this mechanism is entirely based on `lxml` library, quote from [documentation page](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html):

> Scrapy comes with its own mechanism for extracting data. They’re
>   called selectors because they “select” certain parts of the HTML
>   document specified either by XPath or CSS expressions.
>
> Scrapy selectors are built over the lxml library, which means they’re
>   very similar in speed and parsing accuracy.

`lxml` itself is known for it's high performance, you can find the details and benchmarks here:

- [Benchmarks and Speed](http://lxml.de/performance.html)

---

As for best practices for writing xpath expressions, the "gold" rule is try to search over the whole root tree as less as possible, quote from [lxml docs](http://lxml.de/performance.html#xpath):

> A lot of time is usually spent in tree traversal to find the addressed
>   elements in the tree. If you often work in subtrees, do what you would
>   also do with deep Python objects: assign the parent of the subtree to
>   a variable or pass it into functions instead of starting at the root.
>   This allows accessing its descendents more directly.

---

But, be sure you know where your bottlenecks are. I doubt it would be really inside the xpath engine used by Scrapy, or because of the way you've written your xpath expressions. [Do not optimize prematurely](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization), measure!